# Daily reminder option in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I am building an iPhone App that tracks specific information over time. The App should be run daily at about the same time of day, each day over a six month period.

Is there a routine that allows for an alarm to be set once, to notify the user that it is time to run the App again, on an ongoing basis?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is, check out [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)